# how to return rows with a keyword within a string contained in a cell in r

Tags: r, subset

I thought that this would be a simple one line of code, but the solution to my challenge is eluding me. I am betting that my limited experience with the domain of R programming might be the source.

Data Set

```
 df <- structure(list(Key_MXZ = c(1731025L, 1731022L, 1731010L, 1730996L,       
     1722128L, 1722125L, 1722124L, 1722123L, 1722121L, 1722116L, 1722111L,      
     1722109L), Key_Event = c(1642965L, 1642962L, 1647418L, 1642936L,           
     1634904L, 1537090L, 1537090L, 1616520L, 1634897L, 1634892L, 1634887L,      
     1634885L), Number_Call = structure(c(11L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 1L, 3L,            
     2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 7L), .Label = c("3004209178-2010-04468",               
     "3004209178-2010-04469", "3004209178-2010-04470", "3004209178-2010-04471", 
     "3004209178-2010-04472", "3004209178-2010-04475", "3004209178-2010-04477", 
     "3004209178-2010-04478", "3004209178-2010-04842", "3004209178-2010-04850", 
     "I wish to return this row with the header", "Maybe this row will work too"
     ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Key_MXZ", "Key_Event", "Number_Call"    
     ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5",            
     "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```

In the last column I have placed two strings among other data types that would be used to identify the rows for a new dataframe -- using the phrase "this row". The end result might look like:

```
  Key_MXZ|Key_Event|Number_Call
1|1731025|1642965|I wish to return this row with the header
4|1730996|1642936|Maybe this row will work too
```

I have tried the following variations of code and others unseen to breakthrough with little success.

```
txt <- c("this row")
table1 <- df[grep(txt,df),]
table2 <- df[pmatch(txt,df),]
df[,3]<-is.logical(df[,3])
table3 <- subset(df,grep(txt,df[,3]))
```

Any ideas on this challenge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go with

```
df[grep("this row", df$Number_Call, fixed=TRUE),]

#  Key_MXZ Key_Event                               Number_Call
#1 1731025   1642965 I wish to return this row with the header
#4 1730996   1642936              Maybe this row will work too
```

Just needed to reference the actual column you wanted grep to try to match

fixed=TRUE looks for exact matches, and grep returns indeces of those elements in the list that hit the match.  If your match is a bit more nuanced you can replace "this row" with a regular expression

Answer (score 3):

Quite similar to DMTs answer. Below uses data.table approach which is fast in case you have millions of rows:

```
setDT(df); setkey(df, Number_Call)
df[grep("this row", Number_Call, ignore.case = TRUE)]

   Key_MXZ Key_Event                               Number_Call
1: 1731025   1642965 I wish to return this row with the header
2: 1730996   1642936              Maybe this row will work too
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach that uses `qdap`'s `Search` function.  It's a wrapper for `agrep` so it can do fuzzy matching and the degree of fuzziness can be set:

```
library(qdap)
Search(df, "this row", 3)

##   Key_MXZ Key_Event                               Number_Call
## 1 1731025   1642965 I wish to return this row with the header
## 4 1730996   1642936              Maybe this row will work too
```

Comment: Thank you Tyler. I was wondering what version of R and OS you were running. I tried this approach with qdap on R 3.1.1/Win8 and get  an error message "Error in loadNamespace" bc dplyr needs to be >= 0.3 version. I have tried updating dplyr but it remains at .2 for some unknown reason.

Comment: Hmm that stinks.  I think [`dplyr` is working some things out](http://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_dplyr.html).  You might try running `install.packages("dplyr", type="source")` in an R -vanilla session (i.e., dplyr is not loaded).  I am running Win7 R dev version.  But it looks like `dplyr .3.0.1` is on CRAN and now the binaries for Windows will be built in a few days.  I hope some of these kinks they were experiencing will be worked out.  Can you please update me if you are able to use this approach (i.e.,get qdap installed).

Comment: I was hoping to see qdap work. So, maybe as I scale up my code I might try again ?

Comment: What did `install.packages("dplyr", type="source")` do?

Comment: It added two dependencies to the install and initialized those dependencies to examine the architecture of the OS and validate the installs. A few warnings lead into lazy loading (?) and installed dplyr. It appears that it then rolled it back to previous version of dplyr. Anyhow, library(dplyr) works--no problems. However, the namespace conflict with library(qdap) remains.FULL TECHNICAL ANSWER FROM R CONSOLE 3.1.1: [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qwertyone/datasets/master/ForTyler]